# ParseSwift ParseObject QueryConstraint

Tags: swift, mongodb-query, parse-server

I have two collections in a mongo DB.

Here is how a document looks in the first collection (MainCollection):

```
_id
:"mzWqPEDYRU"
TITLE
:"ZAZ: I want."
ownerID
:"lGutCBY52g"
accessKey
:"0kAd4TOmoK0"
_created_at
:2020-03-13T11:42:11.169+00:00
_updated_at
:2020-03-13T17:08:15.090+00:00
downloadCount
:2
```

And here is how it looks in the second collection (SecondCollection):

```
_id
:"07BOGA8bHG"
_p_unit
:"MainCollection$mzWqPEDYRU"
SENTENCE
:"I love nature peace and freedom."
Order
:5
ownerID
:"lGutCBY52g"
AUDIO
:"07067b5589d1edd1d907e96c1daf6da1_VOICE.bin"
_created_at
:2020-03-13T11:42:17.483+00:00
_updated_at
:2020-03-13T11:42:19.336+00:00
```

There is a parent children relationship between the first and the second collection. In the last document we can see the _p_unit field where the "mzWqPEDYRU" part points to the id of the parent in the first collection.

I have one problem from start with the following code:

```
func theFunction() {
    do {MainCollection.query().find() {
            result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let items):
                print("items.count = \(items.count)")
                for item in items {
                    /// ....
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in \(#function): \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The way this above code is written works fine and I get the number of elements in *MainCollection* as one would expect. But then comes a less expected behaviour, in this same code if I replace *MainCollection* by *SecondCollection*, instead of getting the number of elements in *SecondCollection* as I would think. I get an error like:

```
ParseError(code: ParseSwift.ParseError.Code.unknownError, 
message: "Error decoding parse-server response: 
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2837211a0> { URL:} 
{ Status Code: 200, Headers {} }) with error: 
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
Format: Optional(\"{\\\"results\\\": .......
```

Can anybody point out what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It is something like:

```swift
var SecondCollection.query(unit == documentOne).find()
```

Comment: Trying to follow your suggestion, I always get this error: "Cannot find 'unit' in scope". I have checked that unit is present where I think it should be, but I must be missing some detail.

Comment: @Davi_Macêdo. After a few trials, I need to ask where "unit" is supposed to come from. I assumed it was a field in SecondCollection; but all my tests seem to show that my assumption is wrong.

Comment: You have a field in the SecondCollection called unit, right?

Comment: Yes! I have indeed such a field. But here is something I noticed relative to that while trying out a few things. Replacing unit by another field of SecondCollection brings the same error message. This shows that though SecondCollection itself is known in the scope it seems its fieds are unknown.

Comment: Could you share the code on how you are creating and instantiating SecondCollection and also the query?

Comment: @Davi_Macêdo. I have edited the post, I think you should now have all the information you wanted.

Comment: Where you have `unit: Pointer<MainCollection>`, could you please try with `unit: MainCollection`?

Comment: I have tried that, but I still have the error "Cannot find 'unit' in scope", as far as I can see it did not change anything.

Comment: @Davi_Macêdo. I have edited the post, and added some more information at the end. Hoping I am getting closer to something working.

Answer (score 0):

The .query() method works in a key/value scheme so it should pass the key as a string and the value as the referenced type, so passing "unit" between double quotes is correct:

```
do {SecondCollection.query("unit" == cell).find() {
```

The error you're getting is because cell is a Parse.Object and it is expecting a value in that place (a property in this case).

Please try the following and see if it works for you:

```
do {SecondCollection.query("unit" == cell.id).find() {
```

Comment: I have tried to replace "cell" by "cell.id" as you suggest but it does not work. I have also tried to replace "cell" by "cell.objectId", it also fails.

Comment: Which version of the framework are you using?
Also, can you please try this:

    do {SecondCollection.query("unit" == cell).includeAll().find() {

or even:

    do {SecondCollection.query("unit" == cell).include("unit").find() {

Comment: I am using ParseSwift 1.7.1 and have never used any other. As for trying your suggestion, it failed. On the other hand I tried "do {SecondCollection.query().find() {" and got some results, of course with no filtering on unit as I eventually want. But the problem is that instead of getting the result as a success, I get the information embedded inside an error message. 
Like:
Error : ParseError(code: ParseSwift....unknown, 
msge: "Error decoding parse-server response: 
....
 with error: The data .. isn’t .. correct format.
  Format: Optional(\"{"results":[{"objectId":"07BOGA8bHG",

Comment: @Alex_Kusmenkovsky. Digging more into my problem after your last comment made me realize I had to tackle the issue at an upper level. So I have rewritten the post to reflect that. I hope you will be able to take another look at it and let us know what you think.

Comment: After spending quite some time, I discovered that this line "AUDIO: String?" in the declaration of my second collection  was causing much trouble. That means removing it allowed me to list the elements in the collection, without any filtering though. And I will still need to figure out what type I should use for AUDIO instead of using String. This AUDIO fields is simply pointing to an audio file on the server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67955826/making-a-query-on-a-mongo-db-with-parseswift/68105968#68105968

Take a look at this thread. My last answer there might help you achieve what you're trying.